# Datatable not working when another AJAX is used

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

Either The Ajax for select.mop is working or Datatable is working . i want it both to work .

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("select.mop").change(function(){
    var selectedMop = $(".mop option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "client_v_load.php",
        data: { country : selectedMop } 
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#response").html(data);
    });
  });
 });
   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">      
 jQuery(function($) {
 $('#load_payment').DataTable();

 })(jQuery);
 //$(document).ready(function() {
 //$("select.mop").destroy();
 //$('#load_payment').DataTable();
 // } );
</script>
```

only  select.mop is working with dis code , but datatable don't work . if i load the datatable before select.mop than select.mop don't work

Comment: where is this $("select.mop") located? in the datatable?

Comment: i use mop as a ID for select onload in HTML select Tag , and i am using datatable also on same PHP page   . they are separate module but they some how terminate each other .

Comment: this $("#response").html(data); contains the datatable?

Comment: yes sir ,$("#response").html(data);  contains  datatable contains .

Answer (score 0):

try the following: add the datatable initialization in the success function of your ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("select.mop").change(function(){
    var selectedMop = $(".mop option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "client_v_load.php",
        data: { country : selectedMop } 
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#response").html(data);
        $("#response").find('#load_payment').DataTable();
    });
  });
 });
   </script>
```

Comment: Tried , Not Working in my case , DataTable's load_payment is not working after the ajax Call .

Comment: i just checked it , i Don't find any error . @Madalin . Do you want me to share the screen .

Comment: you ajax the complete datatable or just a part of it?

Comment: i load the table with database value where i use table ID load_payment and than i use the <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">  
jQuery(function($) {
$('#load_payment').DataTable();

})(jQuery);
//$(document).ready(function() {
//$("select.mop").destroy();
//$('#load_payment').DataTable();
// } );
</script>

Comment: lets rephrase the question what content does the select box add to the page the whole datatable or just a part of it, i have updated my answer

Comment: select box have client_name ( client_name changes onclick using Ajax , which there by changes the client id ) its add client_id , which help to retrieve the data from  database  and  and this data load in a datatable (data load in table but the css and js of datatable don't called as load_payment is not working ) .

Comment: do you have a url to look at?, can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: i can share my screen , if you want via teamviewer  .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2wtu3vLo/1/  . there ae two page client_v and client_v_load both are in hTMl and javascript  section .

Comment: are you 100% sure you don't have a console error, can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: Sir, i have attache image in the question , the data showing at the bottom in the image must be in datatable format  . But datatable is not working http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ecl4.png

Comment: do you know where the console is? i sad you give me a printscreen of the console not the page, the page doesn't help

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7ehtt.png . this is the console error . i guess

Comment: is this current Update  ?

Comment: i have use this , still showing that console error .

Comment: how can it show the same error if destroy is not present :(

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).DataTable    is not a function : This is the new error

Comment: Try `jQuery("#response").find('#load_payment').DataTable();`

Comment: if this doesn't work then that means you have a problem with the datatable library

Comment: its not working . Thank you for your Help & Time :) i appreciate it :)

Comment: why do you have 2 jquery libraries added to your page?

Comment: you have problems with you datatable library i suggest you use a cdn

Comment: i have used it  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">